# How to reduce title bar height?

Tags: gnome3, gtk3, window-title

I'm running `GNOME 3.18` and I would like to reduce the title bar height.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 41):

After Gnome 3.20, `.header-bar.default-decoration` doesn't work.

You can put follow content into `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```
/* shrink headerbars (don't forget semicolons after each property) */
headerbar {
    min-height: 0px;
    padding-left: 2px; /* same as childrens vertical margins for nicer proportions */
    padding-right: 2px;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
}

headerbar entry,
headerbar spinbutton,
headerbar button,
headerbar separator {
    margin-top: 0px; /* same as headerbar side padding for nicer proportions */
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* shrink ssd titlebars */
.default-decoration {
    min-height: 0; /* let the entry and button drive the titlebar size */
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
}

.default-decoration .titlebutton {
    min-height: 0px; /* tweak these two props to reduce button size */
    min-width: 0px;
}

window.ssd headerbar.titlebar {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    min-height: 0;
}

window.ssd headerbar.titlebar button.titlebutton {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

via https://ogbe.net/blog/gnome_titles.html

Comment: For me, this caused the far-right window buttons to squish together. To fix this, I had to replace lines 13 and 14 (`margin-top`, `margin-bottom`) with simply `margin: 0px;` (which implies all four `margin-*` directions).

Comment: I also had to add `padding-right: 6px;` as line 31 in order to put some padding between the side of the window headerbar and the "close window" X button.

Comment: and similar after @brandones line I add `padding-left: 6px`, to not have the icon from some applications being squished to the edge.

Comment: Here's Robert Lu's CSS with the modifications suggested by brandones & Christian: https://github.com/JackKelly/linux_home/blob/master/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

Comment: how do I apply this?

Comment: You have to log out and log back in

Comment: Reload Gnome without logout: Alt+F2, type letter r, enter

Comment: @Regis - thanks but that wasn't sufficient for me; logging out and back in did work.

Answer (score 14):

To reduce the titlebar size just create a `css` file in this location: `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and copy paste the code below; this will resize the titlebar:

```
.header-bar.default-decoration {
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }

.header-bar.default-decoration .button.titlebutton {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

you can add this code (on the same file) to remove the line under the titlebar to reduce a little bit more the size:

```
/* No line below the title bar */
.ssd .titlebar {
    border-width: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type <kbd>r</kbd> in the box that appears and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to reload the gnome shell.

And you're good to go :)

Answer (score 5):

For maximized windows, I can recommend this Gnome Shell Extension called [Pixel Saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/) by [deadalnix](https://extensions.gnome.org/accounts/profile/deadalnix). The title bar will disappear (which allows more space for notebook users), but you can still see the window title in the black activity bar.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
.titlebar, headerbar {
    min-height: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
headerbar entry,
headerbar spinbutton,
headerbar button,
headerbar separator {
    min-height: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 1px;
}
/*
more or less normal
write this in ~\.config\gtk-3.0\gtk.css
use slashes instead of backslashes
slashes just terrifyin my nano (:
*/
```

[image: my desktop]
Works for Ubuntu 18.04 with gnome-session-flashback

Comment: just writing a file was not enough for me, how do I apply it?

Comment: One must logout/in or reboot to see the changes

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your Linux distribution and the package manager and/or package, install **Gnome Tweak Tool**.

[image: Gnome Tweak Tool]

Select the "*Fonts*" tab in the side-menu.

Then, set the *Text Height* for **Window Titles** to as low a number as you like.

[image: Window Titles Font Selection]

**NOTE**: this is only applicable for older versions of GNOME

Comment: Doesn't change the titlebar size, just the font size in the titlebar so no good.

Comment: This applies to older versions of GNOME only.  It is irrelevant for versions after 3.20, as @RobertLu mentioned in [that answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343643/27776).

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions seem to modify the Adwaita so I found Minwaita solution. 
[Minwaita git here](https://github.com/godlyranchdressing/Minwaita)

Git repo did not include install info.
Instructions to install are move the unzipped

- Minwaita.tar.gz
- Minwaita-OSX.tar.gz
- Minwaita-Vanilla.tar.gz

folder to 
`/usr/share/themes/` 
directory where you will find original Gnome Adwaita folder.
Install the gnome tweak tool to switch themes. 
`└─$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` 
Applications sub menu of tweak tool will show the option for themes.

Others solutions:
https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1174686/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the top bar, the extension [gnome-compact-top-bar](https://github.com/metehan-arslan/gnome-compact-top-bar/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file#gnome-compact-top-bar) helps:

Transparent on desktop:
[image: desktop]

Blacked out, fonts fading on fullscreen:
[image: fullscreen]