# How to change the titlebar height in standard GTK apps and those with headerbars/CSDs on Gnome 3.20

Tags: gnome3, window-manager, nautilus, mutter

In Gnome 3.18, it was possible to change the titlebar height of all windows by changing the css in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` as per [Reduce title bar height in gnome 3 / gtk+ 3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257163/reduce-title-bar-height-in-gnome-3-gtk-3).

```
.header-bar.default-decoration {
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }

.header-bar.default-decoration .button.titlebutton {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

/* No line below the title bar */
.ssd .titlebar {
    border-width: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

In Gnome 3.20, this appears to no longer apply to windows with a headerbar/CSD (gnome-specific buttons in the title bar), such as Nautilus (Files), Settings, Photos, Contacts, etc. The tweak still reduces the titlebar height for other applications, such as gnome-terminal and gVim. How do I reduce the height of the titlebar in gnome-programs such as Nautilus in Gnome 3.20?

---

#### Update

I have also tried what is [suggested in this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/46gplm/does_anyone_know_how_to_decrease_titlebar_height/?sort=old). I tried both `window.ssd` and `.ssd` only, <strike>no dice.</strike> *This works, see the answer I posted for more details*

```
window.ssd headerbar.titlebar {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    min-height: 0;
}

window.ssd headerbar.titlebar button.titlebutton {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

and

```
/* shrink headebars */
headerbar {
    min-height: 38px;
    padding-left: 2px; /* same as childrens vertical margins for nicer proportions */
    padding-right: 2px;
}

headerbar entry,
headerbar spinbutton,
headerbar button,
headerbar separator {
    margin-top: 2px; /* same as headerbar side padding for nicer proportions */
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

/* shrink ssd titlebars */
.default-decoration {
    min-height: 0; /* let the entry and button drive the titlebar size */ 
    padding: 2px
}

.default-decoration .titlebutton {
    min-height: 26px; /* tweak these two props to reduce button size */
    min-width: 26px;
}
```

Comment: fwiw this is a gtk  thing not a gnome/nautilus/wm one

Comment: The solution in your update worked great for me on Arch with Gnome 3.20. Had to adjust the values a bit, and it doesn't extend to GTK3 CSDs, but those are insane anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it is useful! I posted a few comments regarding the CSDs/headerbars  in my answer below, try it out and see if it helps.

Comment: @Mongrel please read this:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283468/whats-the-preferred-format-when-linking-posts-within-the-same-network

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Note: If you are on PopOS, there is an option to "Remove Window Titles" in the top bar menu that also controls tiling. This is what I use currently myself and it works great for only removing the superfluous non-CSD titlebars.*

## Headerbar/CSD

Actually, a section of the code that I found via reddit and posted above, namely

```
headerbar entry,
headerbar spinbutton,
headerbar button,
headerbar separator {
    margin-top: 2px; /* same as headerbar side padding for nicer proportions */
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

**DOES** modify the headerbars/CSDs. However the effect is not immediate. Even if you reload gnome, you might need to close all windows, wait a while, or log out and log back in again to see the effect.

I am still not seeing any difference in the header bar when modifying the following.

```
headerbar {
    min-height: 38px;
    padding-left: 2px; /* same as children's vertical margins for nicer proportions */
    padding-right: 2px;
}
```

## Standard titlebar

The two sections for the normal window titlebars work as expected.

```
.default-decoration {
    min-height: 0; /* let the entry and button drive the titlebar size */
    padding: 2px
}

.default-decoration .titlebutton {
    min-height: 26px; /* tweak these two props to reduce button size */
    min-width: 26px;
}
```

## Titlebar border

You can use the following to remove the titlebar border if you are running the default adwaita theme.
From https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211102

```
window.ssd headerbar.titlebar {
  border: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
  shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.05),
  shade(@theme_bg_color, 0.99));
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.4);
}
```

Comment: Are all these suggested changes made in "~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css" or where exactly?

Comment: @ezra-s Yes, any of the above sections would be added to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

Comment: does this work on gtk4?

Comment: Note that there is a limit to how low you can squeeze the height of CSD Header Bars that are implemented with GTKHeaderBar (or a descendant thereof) if they left the default TRUE value of the `has-subtitle` GTK property alone. In that case, GTKHeaderBar reserves vertical space for two lines of text in some system font, even if there is no subtitle and the actual font that is being used in the title is smaller. And note there is no way to modify the `has-subtitle` property of a GTKHeaderBar from gtk CSS :-(. Hence in this case, a source code change is needed to squeeze out the excess height.

Comment: (Well, you _can_ run the application under the GTK interactive browser debugger -- e.g., by running it with the GTK_DEBUG environment variable set to `interactive` -- and then navigate the GTK object tree to the GTKHeaderBar you want to shrink and then manually modify its `has-subtitle` property to FALSE. But that is a real pain to do on every invocation.)

Answer (score 35):

1. create a file ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css ( add the below CSS )
2. then you will need to reload gnome-shell: `ALT + F2` and type `r`

I was able to reduce the app Titlebar on Gnome 3.20 with the following CSS:

```
headerbar entry,
headerbar spinbutton,
headerbar button,
headerbar separator {
    margin-top: 0px; /* same as headerbar side padding for nicer proportions */
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

headerbar {
    min-height: 24px;
    padding-left: 2px; /* same as childrens vertical margins for nicer proportions */
    padding-right: 2px;
    margin: 0px; /* same as headerbar side padding for nicer proportions */
    padding: 0px;
  }
```

Comment: The `alt+f2` then `r` tip is amazing; thank you!

Comment: note that Alt+F2 does not work with a Wayland session

Comment: You can shrink it a little more by adding `min-height: 10px;` in the `headerbar entry etc` section, and change `min-height: 24px;` in `headerbar` to 16px;

Comment: Does not work on apps using libhandy.

Answer (score 5):

Update your `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` with following content:

```
/* shrink headerbars (don't forget semicolons after each property) */
headerbar {
    min-height: 0px;
    padding-left: 2px; /* same as childrens vertical margins for nicer proportions */
    padding-right: 2px;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
}

headerbar entry,
headerbar spinbutton,
headerbar button,
headerbar separator {
    margin-top: 0px; /* same as headerbar side padding for nicer proportions */
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* shrink ssd titlebars */
.default-decoration {
    min-height: 0; /* let the entry and button drive the titlebar size */
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
}

.default-decoration .titlebutton {
    min-height: 0px; /* tweak these two props to reduce button size */
    min-width: 0px;
}

window.ssd headerbar.titlebar {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    min-height: 0;
}

window.ssd headerbar.titlebar button.titlebutton {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: What is the equivalent of this for gtk4 applications like Nautilus under 22.10? I tried to put a similar file under `~/.config/gtk-4.0`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Tangent to the subject, you can download the [maximums shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1026/maximus-ng/) to hide the title bar on maximized windows. Quite the useful usecase.

Not compatible with wayland as far as I know, but didn't test it.

Answer (score 2):

On my Ubuntu 20.04 I use this custom theme fix (Gnome 3.20 on Yaru Standard Theme) and works well.

```
headerbar.default-decoration {
    min-height: 18px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

headerbar.default-decoration button.titlebutton {
    min-height: 16px;
    min-width: 16px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}


headerbar  {
    min-height: 18px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}


headerbar entry, headerbar spinbutton, headerbar button, headerbar switch, headerbar separator {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}


headerbar button.titlebutton.minimize, headerbar button.titlebutton.maximize, headerbar button.titlebutton.close {
    min-height: 16px;
    min-width: 16px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the `usr/share/themes/name-of-the-theme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css` file.

We have to find

```
 /* Panel */

   #panel {
   background-gradient-direction:none;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   /* border: 0px solid rgba(90,105,111,0.5);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);*/
   border: 1px solid rgba(90,105,111,0.5);
   box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   border-top:0px;border-right:0px;border-left:0px;
   font-weight: bold;
   height: 24px;
```

We have to change the " height " value. Afterwards we have to reload the theme. I use the extension " activities configurator " for the other parameters of the topbar.

Comment: This file is not meant to be edited and will be reset after updating the theme.