# How to change the color of an active window title bar in GNOME?

Tags: gnome3, theme, gtk3

I found on StackExchange how to change the color of the title bar of an inactive window (in GNOME 3):

`~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```css
headerbar.default-decoration {
    background-color: #c00; /* red */
}
```

(See this question: [How to change the titlebar height in standard GTK apps and those with headerbars/CSDs on Gnome 3.20](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276951/how-to-change-the-titlebar-height-in-standard-gtk-apps-and-those-with-headerbars))

[image: Inactive windows colored in #c00]

But how can I change the color of only the active window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that's not correct. `headerbar:backdrop` should be the one for inactive windows, `headerbar` for the active one. I've used headerbar {...} to set the color, like:

```
    headerbar {
  padding: 0 6px;
  min-height: 46px;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: @border_color;
  background: @bg_color linear-gradient(to bottom, shade(@bg_color,1.2), shade(@bg_color, 0.8));
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); }
```

for inactive windows i used:

```
  headerbar:backdrop {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, shade(@bg_color,1.2), shade(@bg_color, 0.8));
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    transition: 200ms ease-out; }
```

You can have it flat using `background-color` instead of `background-image` but I don't like it ;-)
Note that the colors prefixed with @ are part of the theme and have to be defined. Instead of them you can use the rgb notation (eg #FF0000 for red)

Be sure to set the background-image to none if you use the color notion

Comment: I've tried `headerbar { background-color: #c00; } headerbar:backdrop { background-color: #00c; }` but this gives a blue background for inactive windows (as expected) and a default gray background for active ones (expected: red).

Comment: Ok, I have to unset `background-image`, additionally (only for `headerbar`). Then it works. Thank you!

Comment: I've edited my comment to add that point, glad it helped

Answer (score 2):

To change the title color and the background color of Gnome title active window create a custom style:

```
$gedit ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

Put this css content on the file and save it

```css
headerbar {
  color: #f2d2a7 ;
  background-color: #a87532 ;
}

headerbar:backdrop {
  color: #70685e;
  background-color: black ;
}
```

Save the file and then press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type 'r' as the command to restart Gnome and see the results of the above styles.

Be aware that some apps don't follow the gtk scheme changes, make sure you try with different ones to see your changes.

Comment: To get the `background-color` to take effect, I also had to set `background-image: none`.