# How to remove the border under the titlebar in Gnome 3.20?

Tags: gnome3, gtk, window-decorations, mutter

In Gnome 3.20, I can no longer remove the small border under the titlebar using this snippet in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` (suggested here [Reduce title bar height in gnome 3 / gtk+ 3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257163/reduce-title-bar-height-in-gnome-3-gtk-3)).

```
.ssd .titlebar {
    border-width: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Does anyone know what the equivalent would be in Gnome 3.20?

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of tweaking I found that the following CSS snippet when placed in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` works a little better and more inline with the older approach.

```
window.ssd headerbar.titlebar {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
    shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.05),
    shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.00));
}
```

This also fixes the problem with the small color difference at the bottom of the title bar (due to shading to 1.00 instead of 0.99).  I don't know if the `box-shadow` setting is necessary (couldn't tell a difference) but it's mainly just to be consistent.

Comment: I'm on ArchLinux and this didn't work for me after restarting the shell. Is it still working for you? I'm on gnome-shell 3.20.4.

Comment: Ah... I'm sorry. I'm looking for removing the titlebar entirely. Do you know whether it's possible to shrink it to 0?

Comment: It still works for me using gnome-shell 3.20.4 on Fedora 24.

Comment: It's still working on gnome-shell 3.22.2 on Fedora 25.

Comment: @pepper_chico, it's probably possible but I don't know how you'd do it.

Answer (score 2):

I can use the following to remove the titlebar border in the default adwaita theme. From https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211102

```
window.ssd headerbar.titlebar {
  border: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
  shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.05),
  shade(@theme_bg_color, 0.99));
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px shade(@theme_bg_color, 1.4);
}
```

I still have not found a way to do this for other themes, such as Numix.

Comment: I'm on ArchLinux and this didn't work for me after restarting the shell. Is it still working for you? I'm on gnome-shell 3.20.4.

Comment: Ah... I'm sorry. I'm looking for removing the titlebar entirely. Do you know whether it's possible to shrink it to 0?