# How to change the size of the Terminal Titlebar in Terminator?

Tags: gnome-terminator

I'm trying to increase the size of the Terminal Titlebar in Terminator, and can't find a way to do it. Ideally I'd like to do this via some config ([like in gnome shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257163/reduce-title-bar-height-in-gnome-3-gtk-3)). A plugin would be great but I didn't even find a plugin that does that.